# Why can't kepler map in jupyter notebook be rendered on nbviewer

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, widget, kepler.gl

I'm trying to figure out why my map can't be rendered on nbviewer

e.g. https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/zyxue/scratch/blob/master/display-kepler.ipynb?flush_cache=true

I've compared the network activities between nbviewer (left) and jupyter notebook environment (right), still can't figure out why

[image]

reference: https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/blob/master/docs/keplergl-jupyter/user-guide.md

Answer (score 0):

It is because nbviewer can't render dynamic js or css. The same is with github.
You can visit [issues](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/778) and see the trail comments for dynamic support. As of writing this answer this has not been solved.

If you want to show the dynamic graphs, then you can **save notebook widget state** (as in the picture) and then save it as **markdown**. Then you can render it in github.
Here is another example [uncertainty quantification](https://ash1998.github.io/deep%20learning/python/machine%20learning/2018/12/25/Uncertainity-Quantification.html).

[image]

Comment: why plotly works interactively then as in this [example notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/zyxue/scratch/blob/master/display-plotly.ipynb)?

Comment: I tried "Save Notebook Widget State", it does save some [new stuff](https://github.com/zyxue/scratch/commit/c255893579ba78c02737f6f0f48f5cab1b0e5098?diff=split#diff-c91f44fd5244f8cd54bf6a977b844f0eR120-R194), but still doesn't appear to work. Also tried converting to [markdown](https://github.com/zyxue/scratch/blob/master/display-kepler.md), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you can see in the `view page source` in your browser this is not dynamic. The values are stored.

Comment: save widget state wont also render the graphs. You need to use markdown to render it in github.io.

Comment: what do you mean by `dynamic`? could you show me an example of making the kepler map show up?

Comment: nope! go to [this](https://kepler.gl/demo/movement_pittsburgh) link and download the html. Turn your internet off and try opening the html, it won't load. This is dynamic. The json in the html will need to get data in real time. This is what github or nbviewer can't do. There are many reasons...it would consume lots of resources and also for security reasons, they won't know what the code is doing. Atleast right now we don't have that option.